# Finding all possible permutations of the characters in a set of strings using recursion

Tags: recursion, permutation

I have this set of (Greek) strings:

ἸἼΙἹἽ, 
ῇηἤήῃὴῆἡἠἢᾖἥἣῄἦᾗᾐἧᾔᾑ, 
σς, 
οὸόὀὄὅὂ, 
ὺὖυῦύὐὑὔΰϋὕὗὓὒῢ

I'd like to find all possible permutations of the characters in these 5  strings.  For example, Ἰῇσοὺ, Ἰῇσοὖ, Ἰῇσου, etc.  I know it should involve recursion since the number of strings is not fixed but I'm a beginner and I'm completely dumbfounded by recursion.

I did the following in Python and it does give me all combinations of the characters in each string. But I need the 'ἸἼΙἹἽ' to always come first, 'ῇηἤήῃὴῆἡἠἢᾖἥἣῄἦᾗᾐἧᾔᾑ' second,'σς' third, etc.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def Gen( wd, pos, chars ):
    if pos < len( chars ):
        for c in chars:
            for l in c:
                Gen( wd + l, pos + 1, chars )
    else:
        print wd

chars = [ u'ἸἼΙἹἽ', u'ῇηἤήῃὴῆἡἠἢᾖἥἣῄἦᾗᾐἧᾔᾑ', u'σς', u'οὸόὀὄὅὂ', u'ὺὖυῦύὐὑὔΰϋὕὗὓὒῢ' ]

Gen( "", 0, chars )
```

Thanks for the help everybody. My mind is completely blown. Recursion! Here's what I ended up doing in Python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

s = [ u'ἸἼΙἹἽ', u'ῇηἤήῃὴῆἡἠἢᾖἥἣῄἦᾗᾐἧᾔᾑ', u'σς', u'οὸόὀὄὅὂ', u'ὺὖυῦύὐὑὔΰϋὕὗὓὒῢ' ]

results = []

def recur( wd, strings ):
    index = 0
    if index < len( strings ):
        for c in strings[ index ]:
            recur( wd + c, strings[ index + 1: ] )
    else:
        results.append( wd )

def main():
    recur( '', s )
    for r in results:
        print r.encode( 'utf-8' )

main()
```

Comment: Use a pen and paper to figure out the algorithm.

Comment: Ἰῇσοὺ, Ἰῇσοὖ, Ἰῇσου, ... for each u, then each o for each u. then each sigma for each o and u... and so forth.  but I don't know how to code that using recursion.

Comment: You never *have to* use recursion. You can work with for/while loops by starting with an array of all unique characters.

Comment: True, but the number of strings is not fixed. In this case I have 5 strings but in general the user will determine the number of strings.... and the content of each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write down the  five nested loops. In pseudocode,

```py
for a in "ἸἼΙἹἽ"
  for b in "ῇηἤήῃὴῆἡἠἢᾖἥἣῄἦᾗᾐἧᾔᾑ"
    for c in "σς"
      for d in "οὸόὀὄὅὂ"
        for e in "ὺὖυῦύὐὑὔΰϋὕὗὓὒῢ"
           emit [a,b,c,d,e]
```

To encode these *nested* loops with recursion, so it's good for *any number* of input strings, again in pseudocode,

```py
g(list-of-strings) =
   | case list-of-strings
   | of  empty --> end-of-processing
   | of  (first-string AND rest-of-strings) --> 
            for each ch in first-string 
               DO g(rest-of-strings)
```

Now you only need to figure out where to hold each current `first-string`'s character `ch` and how to combine them all while at the `end-of-processing` (basically, your two options are a global accumulator, or an argument to a function invocation).

The latter approach can be coded as

```py
g( picks, list-of-strings) =   # initially, picks = []
   | case list-of-strings
   | of  empty --> end-of-processing( picks )
   | of  (first-string AND rest-of-strings) --> 
            for each ch in first-string 
               DO g( [...picks, ch], rest-of-strings )
```

Answer (score 4):

You create a char array which will contain the string you want to work with
`char str[] = "ABC";`

then you get the length of the string `int n = strlen(str);` and lastly you permutate.

You make a new function which will contain the input string, starting index of the string and ending index of the string.
Check if the starting index (`int s`) equals the ending index (`int e`)
if it does, that means you're done, if not you go into a loop where you go from start (s) to end (e), swap the values, recurse, swap again to backtrack.

An example in C++:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char *i, char *j)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = temp;
}

void permutate(char *str, int start, int end)
{
    int i;
    if (start == end)
        printf("%s\n", str);
    else
    {
        for (i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            swap((str + start), (str + i));
            permutate(str, start + 1, end);
            swap((str + start), (str + i)); //backtrack
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "ABC";
    int n = strlen(str);
    permutate(str, 0, n - 1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not that familliar with Python, but I've found something that might help in your case:

```py
def comb(first_str, second_str):
if not first_str:
    yield second_str
    return
if not second_str:
    yield first_str
    return

for result in comb(first_str[1:], second_str):
    yield first_str[0] + result
for result in comb(first_str, second_str[1:]):
    yield second_str[0] + result

>>> for result in comb("ἸἼΙἹἽ", "ῇηἤήῃὴῆἡἠἢᾖἥἣῄἦᾗᾐἧᾔᾑ"):
print(result)
```