# How do you generate all permutations of a list with repetition in a functional programming language?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, permutation

I'm trying to self-learn some programming in a functional programming language and recently stumbled on the problem of generating all the permutations of length `m` from a list of length `n`, *with* repetition. Mathematically, this should result in a total of `n^m` possible permutations, because each of the `m` 'slots' can be filled with any of the `n` elements. The code I have currently, however, does *not* give me all the elements:

```
let rec permuts n list =
  match n, list with
   0, _ -> [[]]
  | _, [] -> []
  | n, h :: t -> (List.map (fun tt -> h::tt) (permuts (n-1) list))
                 @ permuts n t;;
```

The algorithm basically takes one element out of a list with `m` elements, slaps it onto the front of all the combinations with the rest of the elements, and concatenates the results into one list, giving only `n C m` results.

For example, the output for `permuts 2 [1;2;3]` yields

```
[[1;1]; [1;2]; [1;3]; [2;2]; [2;3]; [3;3]]
```

whereas I actually want

```
[[1;1]; [1;2]; [1;3]; [2;1]; [2;2]; [2;3]; [3;1]; [3;2]; [3;3]]
```

-- a total of 9 elements. How do I fix my code so that I get the result I need? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK your example is in OCaml. Why you added haskell and scala tags?

Comment: Regarding a Haskell version of what seems to be the N-th power Cartesian product of an input list, you can look at this [closely related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62765370/11282404). Beware of excessive memory consumption if things are not invoked in the proper order.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to this. I added all the tags suggested by the website, but I'm removed the irrelevant ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error appears on the second line of:

```
  | n, h :: t -> List.map (fun tt -> h::tt) (permuts (n-1) list)
                 @ permuts n t
```

Indeed, with this you are decomposing the set of n-tuples with k elements as the sum of

- the set of (n-1)-tuples prefixed with the first element
- the set of n-tuples with (k-1) elements

Looking at the cardinal of the three sets, there is an obvious mismatch since

```
k^n ≠ k^(n-1) + (k-1)^n
```

And the problem is that the second term doesn't fit.
To avoid this issue, it is probably better to write a couple of helper function.
I would suggest to write the following three helper functions:

```
val distribute: 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list list
(** distribute [x_1;...;x_n] y returns [x_1::y;...x_n::y] *)
val distribute_on_all: 'a list -> 'a list list
(** distribute_on_all x [l_1;...;l_n] returns distribute x l_1 @ ... @ distribute x l_n *)
val repeat: int -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'a
(** repeat n f x is f(...(f x)...) with f applied n times *)
```

then your function will be simply

```
let power n l = repeat n (distribute_on_all l) [[]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, it's very natural to do this using a list comprehension:

```hs
samples :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
samples 0 _ = [[]]
samples n xs =
  [ p : ps
  | p <- xs
  , ps <- samples (n - 1) xs
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I unfortunately cannot follow your list comprehension part. Could you elaborate a bit more, maybe in pseudocode?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you never want to recurse on the tail of the list, since all your selections are from the whole list.

The Haskell code of @dfeuer looks right. Note that it never deconstructs the list `xs`. It just recurses on `n`.

You should be able to copy the Haskell code using `List.map` in place of the first two lines of the list comprehension, and a recursive call with `(n - 1)` in place of the next line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I wasn't able to translate @dfeur's suggestion correctly. In particular, could you explain what the first two lines are doing and how it is different from my own map implementation above?

Comment: Your map is good. It's the recursion that's not so good. That's what I'm trying to point out, anyway :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think I am indeed recursing on n with the 'permuts (n - 1) list' phrase. I still don't understand why I am not getting all the permutations...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write it in OCaml:

```
let perm src =
  let rec extend remaining_count tails =
    match remaining_count with
    | 0 -> tails
    | _ ->
        (* Put an element 'src_elt' taken from all the possible elements 'src'
           in front of each possible tail 'tail' taken from 'tails',
           resulting in 'new_tails'. The elements of 'new_tails' are one
           item longer than the elements of 'tails'. *)
        let new_tails =
          List.fold_left (fun new_tails src_elt ->
            List.fold_left (fun new_tails tail ->
              (src_elt :: tail) :: new_tails
            ) new_tails tails
          ) [] src
        in
        extend (remaining_count - 1) new_tails
  in
  extend (List.length src) [[]]
```

The `List.fold_left` calls may look a bit intimidating but they work well. So it's a good idea to practice using `List.fold_left`. Similarly, `Hashtbl.fold` is also common and idiomatic, and you'd use it to collect the keys and values of a hash table.